# No bower/npm config files are part of the latest .NET Core 2.0 Web App templates, but client-side libraries are installed

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, bower, asp.net-core-2.0

The latest ASP.NET Core 2.0 template doesn't have a bower config or a packages.json, but comes with client side packages such as bootstrap and jquery. How do we takeover from here and manage these packages. It was straightforward with the previous template simply using the bower config that came with the project to maintain client side packages.

As of now I have been deleting everything in the lib folder, creating a packages.json or bower config manually and reinstalling. Am I missing something here? Why wouldn't they start you out with a config file for the packages that come pre-installed especially since the client-side libraries that are pre-installed are installed from bower.

Comment: Don't start new projects with Bower - it's going away. Bower team recommends Yarn or Webpack.

Comment: @DavidG I read up on this, but so confused why they just ship the templates with the client side libraries as if they came from bower still and nothing to manage them.

Comment: Well, all they did was keep a folder structure. It's not Bower-specific.

Comment: @DavidG all of the packages still have .bower.json files within the dist directories. Am I correct about just deleting everything in the lib folder completely and just starting fresh with npm or yarn?

Comment: Are you sure you have the latest templates installed? However, you can do as you please with those files, they're only there as examples really.

Comment: @DavidG I have the latest version of VS2017 so I am assuming I do. I just didn't expect microsoft to include client side packages without any configuration file for them in their latest template. Is there anything else I can do to ensure I am using the latest templates?

Comment: It's not about having the latest version of Visual Studio, it's about the .Net Core SDK and associated packages. For example https://github.com/dotnet/templating/wiki/Available-templates-for-dotnet-new

Comment: I just did a fresh install of Visual Studio 2017, tried using bower and it failed.  In the error it's mentioning, "(unconfigured)."  I'm just starting a new project and already I'm disappointed.

Comment: @DavidG If I install the latest version of Visual Studio I still have to update the visual studio templates myself?